# Transitions not playing on first load in WinRT XAML App

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

In my WinRT XAML App I have an EntranceThemeTransition on my Main.xaml page which does not play when you first load the application (App.Xaml does a Frame Load of Main.xaml). However once the application is loaded and I navigate away from Main then back it does play. I have noticed this in other WinRT apps I have built.

Is it a known bug or a feature that allows for faster startups? I have spent the time to make a nice intro transition and it is a shame that most users will not see it. Seems like the transition loads in the background while the application loads up and by the time the user lads on the page the transition is complete.

Currently I am playing around with Thread.Wait and some other hacks - but they are not making this a "Fast & Fluid" experience and make the transitions seem chunky when you navigate back to them from another page. Anyone else having issues with this? What are best practices for forcing the entrance animations to play on first load? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I removed some of the larger image assets that were part of the transition (some were in the 120k range) and the remaining assets now animate fine. I am experimenting with cutting down the K size and making the images Embedded Resources. Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have seen the problem go away or at least become less visible when I do a Release build and run the app without debugging.

Otherwise I would show a loading screen with a progress bar and preload the images before the application starts.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this happens mostly because the element has already been created in the XAML tree but the content that these elements are bound to are the only ones that are coming in late when you load the data from a web service. So technically it's being animated but you don't see it because they have no content. You can fix it by using a DeferredContentPresenter that will hold your XAML as a DataTemplate that waits for the VM to indicate that it has loaded the data. Then you can use the LoadContent function on the DataTemplate to create the XAML tree. Now since elements are created and data is also available at the same time, you should see the entrance animations.

You can adapt the code given here :[Deferred loading of XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537300/deferred-loading-of-xaml) and add a IsLoaded property and bind it to the IsLoaded property you will expose from your ViewModel when the VM has finished loading data from the Model layer. When this IsLoaded property changes in the DeferredContentProvider, you will call LoadContent.