# Deferred loading of XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, silverlight

A project I'm working on has some rather complex XAML that is noticeably affecting visual performance.  Quite a few controls are collapsed for the initial state; however, since their XAML is parsed and visual /logical trees built, it's very slow to show what amounts to an almost blank object.

It looks like (and would like confirmation here) that using a ContentControl with an initial state of Collapsed and then embedding the desired control as a DataTemplate for that ContentControl, will defer loading of the desired control in the DataTemplate until the ContentControl is made visible.

I've built a generic DeferredContentControl that listens for the LayoutUpdated event of the main UI control (in general whatever element it is that I want to appear quickly), and when the first LayoutUpdated event of that UIElement fires, I used the Dispatcher to flip the visibility of the DeferredContentControl to true, which causes the control in the DeferredContentControl's DataTemplate to instantiate.  By the time the user has reacted to the initial view of the screen (which is now fast), the "slow to load" (but still collapsed) control in the data template is ready.

Does this seem like a sound approach? any pitfalls?  It seems to work well in testing both for Silverlight and WPF, and while it doesn't make things any faster it gives the perception of being as much as 50% snappier in my specific scenario.

Comment: I would not rely on the LayoutUpdated, it fires far too often.

Comment: right, I unwire the listener on the first firing of the event

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem (in a Silverlight project), and solved it in nearly the same way. It proved to be working as expected, have not encountered any pitfalls yet.

When you need to control the point in time when xaml is parsed and view elements are instantiated you can always use `DataTemplates` (not necessarily in cunjuction with `ContentControl`). You can call `DataTemplate.LoadContent()` to instatiate it, you don't have to switch the visibility of a ContentControl (although internally this will result in such a LoadContent call).

Have a look at my implementation if you want, it can even display a static text message while the heavier VisualTree is build:

```
<DeferredContent HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <DeferredContent.DeferredContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <MyHeavyView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Controls:DeferredContent.DeferredContentTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="Loading content..."/>
</Controls:DeferredContent>
```

and the code

```
public class DeferredContent : ContentPresenter
{
    public DataTemplate DeferredContentTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(DeferredContentTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DeferredContentTemplateProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DeferredContentTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DeferredContentTemplate",
        typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(DeferredContent), null);

    public DeferredContent()
    {
        Loaded += HandleLoaded;
    }

    private void HandleLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Loaded -= HandleLoaded;
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(ShowDeferredContent);
    }

    public void ShowDeferredContent()
    {   
        if (DeferredContentTemplate != null)
        {
            Content = DeferredContentTemplate.LoadContent();
            RaiseDeferredContentLoaded();
        }
    }

    private void RaiseDeferredContentLoaded()
    {
        var handlers = DeferredContentLoaded;
        if (handlers != null)
        {
            handlers( this, new RoutedEventArgs() );
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs> DeferredContentLoaded;
}
```

Comment: Nice... I had worked with LoadContent but somewhat differently and was always getting a separate instance, but I didn't think to create a DP for the deferred template.  I also had some issues with some attached behaviors, for which the AssociatedObject was null, but was able to work around those.

In terms of LayoutUpdated vs. Loaded, the non-deterministic behavior of Loaded in Silverlight made me shy away from Loaded, but it's quite possible that in this context it wouldn't matter.  May take a closer look at it to convince myself one way or the other.

Comment: So far I have only positive experience with the Loaded event.

Comment: I think, the base class must be `ContentControl` rather than `ContentPresenter`.

Comment: @SebastianKrysmanski `ContentPresenter` was chosen deliberately, it is the superclass for `ContentControl`

Comment: It works fine, but I've found that if I use HandyControl's ToggleBlock with `IsChecked="True"` (literal), it still works fine, but if `IsChecked="{Binding Foo}"` and Foo defaults to True, the ToggleBlock's UnCheckedContent content is also loaded. (I use DeferredContent for both the ToggleBlock's UnCheckedContent and CheckedContent.)

Comment: I found a solution: `IsChecked="{Binding Foo, FallbackValue={x:Null}}"` (If " indeterminate state" is not required.). The reason for this problem seems to be that XAML parsing precedes data binding, and `FallbackValue` seems to override the default values of dependent properties.

Comment: @CodingNinja I can't see how your comments relate to my answer. Did you mean to post these comments to some other Stackoverflow question/answer you had open in another browser tab?

Comment: @Martin Sorry, after finding a solution I realized that the problem I was having had nothing to do with your answer and I didn't need to post a new question for a while.